# Extracting words from observation and matching them with others in data table

Tags: sas

I have data like this

```
Code Sx1 Sx2 Sx3 SX4
P1  XX  AA  ZZ  HH
P2  AA  XX  AA  BB
RR1 XA  XX  ZA  HB
RR2 AA  XA  ZA  BH
RR3 AX  AX  ZZ  HH
RR4 AA  AA  AA  BB
RR5 XX  XX  ZA  HB
RR6 AX  XA  ZZ  HH
RR7 AA  AX  AA  BB
RR8 XX  AA  AZ  HH
```

I want to extract one letter from P1 (X) and another letter from P2 (A) and then I want to use those extracted letters (AX or XA) to match with observations from RR1 to RR8, if they match then 1, not then will be 0. I want to use arrays because my data contains over 8,000 observations. 
I want like this

```
SX1 SX2 SX3 SX4
1   0   1   1
0   1   1   1
1   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   1   0
```

I am trying to solve this by using Substr function

```
Data x; 
Set y; 
var1 = SUBSTR (SX1,1,1); 
var2= SUBSTR (SX2,1,1); 
var3= SUBSTR (SX3,1,1); 
var4= SUBSTR (SX4,1,1);
PACKAGE_SUBSTR = LETTER_1|| LETTER_2|| LETTER_3;
RUN;
```

I will use arrays to store my variables from SX1-SX4 and then

Here after I want to match this concatenated variable with the other observations in the array to reach my goal. I want to know I am proceeding in the right way or not? help needed to solve this problem.

Comment: You have 8000 observations and 4 SX1-SX4 variables, or do you have more than those 4 variables?

Comment: Thank you very much Joe for helping me, actually i have 44 variables here i metioned only 4, i just want to extract one letter from both P1 and P2 for one variables for example SX1 and if i get extracted letters like XA and then i want to match them with remaining observation of SX1 vars. If observation of var SX1 matched then 1 else 0.Thanking you very much

Answer (score 0):

The solution I would use is to transpose your dataset so that instead of 44 variables (or whatever) you have one row per variable.  Then merge them together.  That way it is very flexible and can accommodate any number of variables.  Something like this:

```
data have;
input Code $ Sx1  $ Sx2 $ Sx3 $ SX4 $;
datalines;
P1  XX  AA  ZZ  HH
P2  AA  XX  AA  BB
RR1 XA  XX  ZA  HB
RR2 AA  XA  ZA  BH
RR3 AX  AX  ZZ  HH
RR4 AA  AA  AA  BB
RR5 XX  XX  ZA  HB
RR6 AX  XA  ZZ  HH
RR7 AA  AX  AA  BB
RR8 XX  AA  AZ  HH
;;;;
run;

data p1(drop=code rename=value=value1) p2(drop=code rename=value=value2) code;
set have;
array vars sx1-sx4;
do _t = 1 to dim(vars);
  varname = vname(vars[_t]);
  value = vars[_t];
  if code='P1' then output p1;
  else if code='P2' then output p2;
  else output code;
end;
keep code varname value;
run;

proc sort data=p1;
by varname;
run;
proc sort data=p2;
by varname;
run;
data type1 type2;
merge p1 p2;
by varname;
value = cat(substr(value1,1,1),substr(value2,2,1));
output type1;
value = cat(substr(value2,2,1),substr(value1,1,1));
output type2;
keep varname value;
run;

proc sort data=code;
by varname value;
run;
proc sort data=type1;
by varname value;
run;
proc sort data=type2;
by varname value;
run;
data code_match;
merge code(in=c) type1(in=t) type2(in=t);
by varname value;
if c;
if c and t then match=1;
else match=0;
run;

proc sort data=code_match;
by code varname;
run;
proc transpose data=code_match out=want;
by code;
id varname;
var match;
run;
```

You probably need to adjust the rules somewhat for your needs, I'm not sure if I implemented them correctly, but it does for this example get your desired dataset.  The variables may not be in proper order in this case since you have SX4 capitalized (capitals sort before lower case by default).

Comment: Joe , Thank you very much for your help and your code is working fine and i made changes as per my requirement.